# When I call the notifyListeners() method, the values I entered in the Textfield return to their initial value

Tags: flutter

When I change the "Ulke" value from the AsyncSelectInputForm, I call the notifyListeners() method so that the "Il" value is null.

When I do this, the value I entered in the "Adres Başlığı" TextInputForm returns to its initial value.

My widget:

```html
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var cariAdres = Provider.of<CariAdresProvider>(context);

    return  Column(
              children: [
                TextInputForm(
                    initialValue: cariAdres.cariAdres?.adresBasligi,
                    label: "Adres Başlığı",
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      cariAdres.cariAdresTemp =
                          cariAdres.cariAdresTemp?.copyWith(
                        adresBasligi: value,
                      );
                    },
                    ),

                //todo ulke select
                AsyncSelectInputForm(
                    pageTitle: "Ülke Seç",
                    label: "Ülke",
                    initialLabel: cariAdres.cariAdresTemp?.ulkeIdStr,
                    labelSetter: (item) {
                      return item.ulkeStr;
                    },
                   
                    onChanged: (value, item, context) {
                      cariAdres.cariAdresTemp =
                          cariAdres.cariAdresTemp?.copyWith(
                        ulkeId: value,
                        ulkeIdStr: item.ulkeStr,
                        ilId: null,
                        ilIdStr: null,
                      );
                      cariAdres.notifyListeners();

                    },
                    fetchPage: //...,
                   ),
                //todo il select
                AsyncSelectInputForm(
                    initialValue: cariAdres.cariAdresTemp?.ilId,
                    //... same code 
                   )
    //....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had set the initialValue of TextInputForm to value `cariAdres.cariAdres?.adresBasligi`  and valued `cariAdres.cariAdresTemp?.ulkeIdStr` to AsyncSelectInputForm's initialLabel.

I was able to fix this problem by replacing the `cariAdres.cariAdres?.adresBasligi`  value with the `cariAdres.cariAdresTemp?.adresBasligi`  value. :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be related a lot of possibilities, so we can't be sure which one is correct. But you can try to add some debugPrint in your build method in this way, you can expand your understanding for the situation.

Also, it can be about some logic in your change notifier provider or it can be about your widget tree-state or it can be about your sub widgets.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I solved the problem. :)